# Cannot access nested property from an array of object TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to access the property `placeOfBirth` in the function `foo()`

```
interface Birthday {
    placeOfBirth: string,
    age: number,
} 

interface Dogs {
    name: string,
    color: string,
    age?: Birthday
}

interface Cats {
    race: string,
    color: string,
    vicious: boolean,
    age?: Birthday
}

type Animals = {
    allAnimals: {
        dogs?: Dogs[],
        cats?: Cats[]
    }
}

const myAnmials: Animals = {
    allAnimals: {
        dogs: [],
        cats: []
    }
}

type AnimalKeys = keyof Required<Animals>['allAnimals']

const foo = (index: number, key: AnimalKeys) => {
    const notWorking = myAnmials.allAnimals[key]?[index]?.age.placeOfBirth
}
```

Like this it is nor working. However, when I do it like this

```
const bar = (index: number, key: AnimalKeys) => {
    const working = myAnmials.allAnimals[key]?[index];
    if("age" in working) {
        const selectedAnimal = working.age
    }
}
```

it works. I do understand why. Is there any way to access it this way `myAnmials.allAnimals[key]?[index]?.age.placeOfBirth`?
Here is a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=41&ssc=2&pln=36&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELCmAFgEzgT2QG8BYAKGUuQAcAbRCAeRnUywC5kBnMKUAcwA05Ksjj8InEAFcAtgCNowsgF9k5cqEiwGyACIB7fl2IiqIOLMndeA5aIQHaBqJx58QQs5XEQA-Jys2Hj45CoaZFrQ8EjIAMJwYCakFFRQDG62nvZUjs6uNh5eqZQAbsAIwAbSXJzyBk4QcCA5PhIBaBjBBGERYPjUKACCIMCycLQmALymJWK0tCNjE7WzoqI4RlwdhsYA2gC6resIiducCUmH3sjhqhGOIDzIsvgjssArnEvjk8gzKVEE0Wo1%20q0B60om2MnEOxwcZ1hBxudzu5H6g2QPwmAGkIPhpsgANb4gwwZAAJQgAEdpBgIDgADzYyYAPj2AHJgSyuBzkWQHgYnmBkPI4FB-sgABSgHAQAAeUjkiiggmJ%20O%20oNx%20K4AEp-qy1rkhc8AO4uIkCSWvd6fSYAOm5WsmexJ%20AOfj2soVBwA3DdgDApQAiXzB5CgZDmqCWzz6iGQx7PLgQWgQBCQHAsyXR2P8R0SFG9AVkJMimANSUykByxXIGQKJTq-Ca5a0PEE-VTQ0J5Bl%20sGMAAdQtVpmNpAHxWjoWPNd%20I9XprPr8BYg9roDGYQSwYSAA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is intended, but prior to dynamic key access there should be `?.` not just `?`.

The right way:

```
myAnmials.allAnimals[key]?.[index]?.age?.placeOfBirth
```

Also, your working version isn't actually working since `working` is possibly `undefined` and you can't use the `in` operator with `undefined`.

Both version corrected:

```
const bar = (index: number, key: AnimalKeys) => {
    const working = myAnmials.allAnimals[key]?.[index];
    if(working && "age" in working) {
        const selectedAnimal = working.age
    }
}

const foo = (index: number, key: AnimalKeys) => {
    const notWorking = myAnmials.allAnimals[key]?.[index]?.age?.placeOfBirth
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgELCmAFgEzgT2QG8BYAKGUuQAcAbRCAeRnUywC5kBnMKUAcwA05Ksjj8InEAFcAtgCNowsgF9k5cqEiwGyACIB7fl2IiqIOLMndeA5aIQHaBqJx58QQs5XEQA-Jys2Hj45CoaZFrQ8EjIAMJwYCakFFRQDG62nvZUjs6uNh5eqZQAbsAIwAbSXJzyBk4QcCA5PhIBaBjBBGERYPjUKACCIMCycLQmALymJWK0tCNjE7WzoqI4RlwdhsYA2gC6resIiducCUmH3sjhqhGOIDzIsvgjssArnEvjk8gzKVEE0Wo1+q0B60om2MnEOxwcZ1hBxudzu5H6g2QPwmAGkIPhpsgANb4gwwZAAJQgAEdpBgIDgADzYyYAPj2AHJgSyuBzkWQHgYnmBkPI4FB-sgABSgHAQAAeUjkiiggmJ+O+oNx+K4AEp-qy1rkhc8AO4uIkCSWvd6fSYAOm5WsmexJ+AOfnte1lCoOAG4bsAYFLzVBLZ5kAAySPIABEvljyFAyFD4f4+ohkMezy4EFoEAQkBwLMlqYEjokKN6ArI2ZFMAakplIDliuQMgUSnV+E1y1oeIJ+qmhszyDr7YMYAA6harTMbSAPitHQsea78R6vT75ZvfJ66AxmEEsGEgA)